# How to break two lines together when zooming?

Tags: android, html

This question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32160654/how-to-break-two-lines-together-with-css-javascript-jquery) but was not answered.

I'm making an android app that display song lyrics with chords.
The pattern is this:

Chords
Lyrics
Chords
Lyrics
Chords
Lyrics
......

I'm using a WebView to display the lyrics and an example of data giving to the WebView is this:

```html
<font color='#cc0029'>Em                      G</font><br />
Today is gonna be the day<br />
<font color='#cc0029'>                               D                                  A</font><br />
that they gonna throw it back to you,<br />
<font color='#cc0029'>Em                                 G</font><br />
by now you should have somehow<br />
<font color='#cc0029'>      D                                                          A</font><br />
realized what you gotta do.<br />
<font color='#cc0029'>Em                                          G                   D                         A              </font><br />
I don't belive that anybody feels the way I do<br />
<font color='#cc0029'>                                C          D              A</font><br />
about you now.<br />
```

(Relpaced `&nbsp;` with spaces for visibility)

(And here I'm using `_` instead of space beacause of StackOverflow editor)

**What I've got before zooming:**

> Em______________G
>   Today is gonna be the day
>   _____________________D_________________A
>   That they're gonna throw it back to you,
>   Em____________________G
>   By now you should have somehow
>   ____D______________________________________A
>   Realised what you gotta do
>   Em____________________________G____________D____________________A
>   I don't believe that anybody feels the way I do
>   _______________________C____D____A
>   about you now.

**What I've got after zooming:**

> Em______________G
>   Today is gonna
>   be the day
>   _____________________D_________________A
>   That they're
>   gonna throw it
>   back to you,
>   Em____________________G
>   By now you
>   should have 
>    somehow
>   ____D______________________________________A
>   Realised what
>   you gotta do
>   Em____________________________G____________D____________________A
>   I don't believe
>   that anybody feels
>   the way I do
>   _______________________C____D____A
>   about you now.

**What I want to achieve:**

> Em
>   Today is gonna
>    G
>   be the day
>   ___________.
>   That they're
>   _______D
>   gonna throw it
>   _____________A
>   back to you,
>   Em
>   By now you
>   ___________G
>   should have
>   ___________.
>   somehow
>   ____D
>   Realised what
>   ______________A
>   you gotta do
>   Em
>   I don't believe
>   ______________G
>   that anybody feels
>   ________D_______A
>   the way I do
>   __________C___D___A
>   about you now.

How can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to group the lines by breakpoint

```css
.line>div {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap
}

.chord {
  color: #cc0029;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
  <div>
    <div class="chord">Em</div>
    Today is gonna
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="chord">G</div>
    be the day
  </div>
</div>
<div class="line">
  <div>
    <div class="chord"></div>
    that they gonna
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="chord">D</div>
    throw it back to
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="chord">A</div>
    you,
  </div>
</div>
```

Since there are only a finite number of chords in a song and each chord corresponds with a particular snippet of lyrics, it should be fairly easy to do. Wrapping the set of snippets that make up a line in a div ensures there will always be a break at the end of the line, regardless of whether there is space to continue on the same line.

This also has the benefit of eliminating your alignment using whitespace, which is very brittle.